# Error in max-if function .

Tags: google-sheets, max, preferences

I am not able to work around a max-if formula in google sheets . What am I doing wrong ?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BfGX85iur0Nk1gjsa-lZ3hnFnNNvgK9rFgTkOvhFSIw/edit?usp=sharing

In cell K3 , have inserted a formula where it picks the highest amount from column F when column A matches H3. This works perfectly in cell K2 but I fail to understand whats gone wrong in the subsequent rows.

Answer (score 1):

change
`=max(IF(A:A=H2,F:F))` to `=max(filter(F:F,A:A=H2))`

Comment: Thanks a ton , it works perfectly now .. But how did the first cell K2 work correctly but not the next one

Comment: I don't know (maybe it's a bug?). `if()` is not supposed to handle array without wraping it with  `arrayformula`. Google's documentation is fairly poor, and it's not always clear what function works or don't work with array, so you need to do some experimentation to see if you need `arrayformula` or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own formula you'll need to insert ArrayFormula.

```
=max(ArrayFormula(IF(A:A=H2,F:F)))
```